# How to remove the "frozen" state of a worksheet using ExcelJS?

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I am attempting to utilize ExcelJS to remove the "frozen" state of a worksheet. My Code is as follows:

```
const workbook = new Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(excel_path);
const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheet_name);

if(worksheet){
    if(worksheet?.views[0]){
        (worksheet.views as any) = [{
            state: 'normal',
            zoomScale: 100,
            zoomScaleNormal: 100,
            rightToLeft: false,
            showGridLines: true,
            showRowColHeaders: true,
            showRuler: true,
            workbookViewId: (worksheet.views[0] as any).workbookViewId,
        }];
    }
}
await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(excel_path);
```

However, upon saving and subsequently attempting to open the saved Excel file with Microsoft Excel, an alert is presented indicating an issue with the worksheet's view that necessitates repair.
I read the saved file using the following code, and then get the worksheet's view property:

```
const workbook = new Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(excel_path);
const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheet_name);

if(worksheet){
    console.log(worksheet.views);
}
```

The result I got is:

```
[{
    state: 'frozen',
    zoomScale: 100,
    zoomScaleNormal: 100,
    rightToLeft: false,
    showGridLines: true,
    showRowColHeaders: true,
    showRuler: true,
    xSplit: 0,
    ySplit: 0,
    topLeftCell: "A1",
    workbookViewId: 0,
}]
```

Indeed, there is a problem. I would like to ask how to correctly remove the "frozen" property of a worksheet?

I have also submitted [a same issue to the Issues section of the ExcelJS repository](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/2598) on GitHub. Appreciate your assistance. :)